# Prevent parallelization of jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jobs

I am faced with the task of automating the build and test process for 4 software products in Jenkins. As many steps as possible should run in parallel.

[image]

The build of all four products can run in parallel. However, the test can only be parallelized by products 3 and 4. The test process of 1 and 2 must be sequential.

How would you basically design the automation in Jenkins?

- If I create 4 separate pipelines, it needs to be ensured that the test process of 1 and 2 does not run in parallel.
- Is it easier to create a single pipeline and prevent parallelization of 1 and 2 using job dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution off the top of my head would be something like this:

[image]

Run all the build jobs in one stage and have all of them inside a `parallel` block.

Then you create a new stage that runs **after** all the build stages have completed. This stage will also have a parallel block. Tests 3 and 4 will run in parallel while 1 and 2 run sequentially.

Comment: Good idea, thanks for the illustration. I will try it this way. By chance, I stumbled across the "throttle concurrent builds" plug-in, which also promises solutions for this problem.